# Translating "accept the journey" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Please can you tell me if '*iter suscipere*' is a correct translation of the phrase 'accept the journey' most particularly in the context of where I am taking it from, which is this:

> "Accept the journey. Be at peace in it. Watch it. When you can be at one with the difficulty and the chaos, then you transcend it. You simply walk your path, being observant, paying attention, learning and growing in your understanding of who you are and what is possible for you."

(Ilgner, Arno. The Rock Warrior's Way: Mental Training For Climbers. Desiderata Institute.)

Answer (score 5):

The verb *suscipere* is the passive imperative. The active form would be:

> Iter suscipe.